# Employee is able to edit files in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still fairly new to rails.

In my jobs/index.html.erb file I currently have a conditional  as follows:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_job_path(job) %></td>
  <%end%>
```

Now although the editing is forbidden on the employee side, because it clearly states "if current_user_admin" however if an employee were to login and type localhost:3000/jobs/1/edit they are somehow granted access to change the file.

How can I block the user who is NOT an admin from having the ability to do this?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're preventing them from seeing the link, you need to prevent them from accessing the feature. Add code to your controller that checks their status and prevents unauthorized users from doing things they shouldn't.

```
class JobsController
  def edit
    if !current_user.admin?
      redirect_to '/'
      return
    end

    // Old code here

  end
end
```

If you are going to have a complex set of permissions, consider using a gem like Devise or Cancan. I don't have experience with those, but they seem to be the standards for authorization in rails.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to forbid access to some parts of your application the right place to do it is in `controller`, not in views (hiding links doesn't work as you see). The common solution is to define `before_filter` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) in your controller.

In your particular case this should work

```
class JobsController do

  before_filter :authorize!, only: [:edit,:update]

  #CRUD below

  def authorize!
    redirect_to(:back) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

You could also add message to `flash` before redirecting to let user know what's going on.

```
  def authorize!
    redirect_to(:back, alert: "YOu are not allowed to do it") unless current_user.admin?
  end
```

also adding `status: :403` would be nice in case building api (403 is knows as `forbidden` response)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem to define abilities for different types of users.
Another option is to make a redirecton in edit view for unauthorized users

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in the view - it's just UI. You can put a test directly in the controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def update
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

I use a 404 (not found) but you may prefer a 403 (not authorized), depending if you want the user to know there is something there that he has no access to.

Answer (score 0):

You have protected the display of the link, which is good, so the benign user won't be surprised when it doesn't work.  But as you point out, for the amlignant user, this is trivial to bypass.  You need to add a guard in the destination controller as well.

But you really should check out some gems that provide exactly this type of security.  Cancan seems to be the most widely used.